# Getting the betas of a logistic regression tuned with CalibratedClassifierCV

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, scikit-learn, logit, calibration

**Is there a way, after calibrating a logistic regression, to average out the 3 resulting logistic regressions' coefficients into a single Logit?**

Example (in sklearn):

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

calibrated_logit = CalibratedClassifierCV(LogisticRegression(), cv=3)
calibrated_logit.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This code will generate 3 models, each of which will emit a different proba, which then gets averaged out. Is there a way to combine the coefficients of each logit into a single one that would achieve the same effect?

---

Note: I'm aware that there are a number of publications claiming that logistic regressions to not need to be calibrated, but I've been finding 
considerable empirical evidence to the contrary in highly unbalanced datasets.